# Xcode 9 beta 4 beta 6, macOS 10.13 beta 7 Simulator can't render screens

Tags: xcode9-beta, macos-high-sierra

When I launch my Simulator, it shows as following, I don't know it is a problem about my computer or the Xcode. Anyone can help me, thanks.
[image]